# A severe error occurred with Table Type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We are declaring a table type in our SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.PaymentResult AS TABLE
(
      ID INT NULL,
      PlacementPaymentID INT NOT NULL,
      PaymentAllocationID INT NULL,
      PaymentTypeID INT NOT NULL,
      CostCentreID INT NOT NULL,
      CostCentreTeamID INT NOT NULL,
      TeamID INT NOT NULL, 
      PaymentValue DECIMAL(20,10) NOT NULL,
      DateAllocated DATE NOT NULL,
      AffectedDate DATE NOT NULL,
      DailyAllocationTypeID INT NOT NULL,
      PlacementID INT NULL 
)
GO
```

We then have a function, which takes that table type (created above) as a parameter, and returns a result set:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_PayCarerOnceValidation] (
        @PaymentResultsParam dbo.PaymentResult READONLY
)
RETURNS @Results TABLE (
        ID INT NOT NULL
      , PlacementID INT NOT NULL
      , Date DATE NOT NULL
      , Amount DECIMAL(18,10)
      , CanBePaid BIT NOT NULL
      -- REMOVE Placement ID, Date, CanBePaid
)
AS
BEGIN
```

Within the function, we declare a NEW table variable, and select the data from our incoming parameter (which is the Table Type) into the new table variable, as we need to update values within it:

So, first we declare the new Table Variable, BASED on the Table Type:

```
DECLARE @PaymentResults as dbo.PaymentResult
```

And then insert from the function parameter, into the table variable:

```
INSERT INTO @PaymentResults (ID,PlacementPaymentID,PaymentAllocationID,PaymentTypeID,CostCentreID,CostCentreTeamID,TeamID, PaymentValue,DateAllocated,AffectedDate,DailyAllocationTypeID,PlacementID)
      SELECT
              ID
            , PlacementPaymentID
            , PaymentAllocationID
            , PaymentTypeID
            , CostCentreID
            , CostCentreTeamID
            , TeamID
            , PaymentValue
            , DateAllocated
            , AffectedDate
            , DailyAllocationTypeID
            , PlacementID
      FROM @PaymentResultsParam
```

When we run the procedure that does all this, we seem to be crashing SQL Server!

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on the
>   current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded. Msg 0,
>   Level 20, State 0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on the current
>   command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Can anyone see what we're doing wrong, and why we're killing the server instance? If we remove the last bit of code (Inserting into the table variable), the crash doesn't happen.

Please note. I do not get an error on the first execution. It only fails the second time I run it. By then, as the server had restarted its self, the next time, it works. Then our crashes again.

Additional info: We changed the function, into a stored procedure - and it works as expected! Only when it's a FUNCTION, does it fails. It works the first time the function is called - but fails the next time (Same data). It's as if the table variable is 'locked'?

Also, we have tried this on two separate server instances, different data sets, and it fails the same way on both.

Comment: DECLARE @PaymentResults as dbo.PaymentResult,if this is table variable then its declaration is wrong.Declare PaymentResults  table (col1,col2.........).first correct this then ask further.

Comment: @KumarHarsh - no, that's the correct declaration if you're using a user-defined table type. See [Example D for `DECLARE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to reproduce the issue. If I take the code you've shown and add the minimum to make it compile (populate `@Results`, `RETURN` and `END`), and then add a minimal bit of script to actually use the `udf_PayCarerOnceValidation` function, it executes fine and returns results (Reproduced in SQL Server 2008 R2, Express)

Comment: I thought,that is table variable declaration.Read your post carefully line by line.there is little confusion.Anyway,I think you should your function script and part of code where you are calling and using it.Also are you sure you hv posted complete error message .are you trying to do some DML inside function on any permanence table ?

Comment: Sorry guys. I missed an important bit if info, and have added it to the question. Please note. I do not get an error on the first execution. It only fails the second time I run it.